# Can Roman numerals stand for any kind of Latin numbers?

Tags: grammar-choice, abbreviations, numbers

Latin has four classes of number words.
Can Roman numerals (**I**, **II**, …) be used to for any class, or should they be restricted to, say, cardinals and ordinals?
For example, can **I** abbreviate any of *unus*, *primus*, *singuli*, and *semel* (appropriately declined), and **X** any of *decem*, *decimus*, *deni*, *decies*?
In English, Roman numerals are mainly used for ordinal numbers, but my question concerns Latin.

Comment: @BenKovitz To me "numeral" means a number word such as "three" or "quattuor", whereas "number" means something like "214" or "CCXIV". Are you sure your edit to reverse this is correct?

Comment: Numerals are the symbols (1, 2, 3 .... I, II, III ....) which represent numbers (one, two, three ...)

Comment: I've seen the numerals used to represent both cardinals and ordinals, but never things like distributives (singuli, deni) or adverbs (semel, decies). I'll be interested to see whether others have encountered those uses. There's also the use of numerals as a prefix in terms like Xvir (decemvir), VIvir (sevir), IIIvir (triumvir).

Comment: Yes. Numbers are abstract quantities, numerals are specific representations thereof. See [Numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system), [Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals), [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals), [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals), [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=number+vs.+numeral&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl), [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/numeral#English), etc. English vocabulary finds a way to distinguish almost anything!

Comment: @BenKovitz I don't mind being corrected; I'm happy to learn. It's not important for the question itself, but I can't resist commenting. // Aren't both *tres* and **III** representations of an abstract quantity? By your definition they'd both be numerals. I could accept that. I view the Roman number **CL** the same way as the (Arabic) decimal number 150. And also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(linguistics)) (not a good authority, I know) seems to agree with me that numerals are number words.

Comment: In ordinary formal English, words are normally exempted from being called numerals; see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/numeral#English). The use of "numeral" for a number word is a specialized term of art in linguistics, not in common use. In ordinary language, numerals are _figures,_ i.e. little shapes that you can draw, that stand for numbers in a compact way. If you start with Roman numerals and Arabic numerals and generalize from there, you'll have the idea. The term is naturally extended to Church numerals, which are themselves mathematical abstractions in need of a representation.